# Does Mulesoft component of WMQ support "cacheConsumers" property?

Tags: mule

We're facing 'WMQ' stopped issue when MQ restart.

May I know following questions?
1. Does Mulesoft component of WMQ support "cacheConsumers" property? 
2. Does anyone know how what's reason of this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the bit more details . Cross check whether you have enabled re-connection property in connector. If this is not enabled, connection between mule and WMQ lost. It wont try to reconnect again.

[image]

Refer: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-reconnection-strategies